# Retain conditional formatting with pandas.ExcelWriter() and engine = openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a bunch of excel files from a template file that contains conditional formatting for the cell range I will be populating with data.

I create a dataframe from an excel file that contains all the airports in a state with a bunch of data columns that describe the airport. I then want to make a summary file for each airport that is basically the airport's row extracted and placed into a new excel file as a column, with some additional columns. Currently all this is working.

However, when I write the dataframe to the new file created from the template excel file, everything else in the new file is retained (other filled cells are still there), except the conditional formatting does not show up. When I look at the conditional formatting rules in the new file, the rule is there, but the format portion is reset. See images below:

Template file formatting:
[image: template file formatting](borders present)]

Formatting in new file (copied from template and populated from dataframe):
[image: formatting in new file](no borders)]

So here's the code:

Create the output file name, copy template and save with new name:

```
# ap is the single airport row extracted from the master frame (series here)
ap_name = ap['Airport Name'].replace('/', '-').strip()
ap_id = ap['Airport Identifier']
file_name = '{} ({}).xlsx'.format(ap_name, ap_id)
output_ap_file = path.join(output_folder, file_name)
shutil.copy(input_template_file, output_ap_file)  # copy template and create new file
```

Note: If I look at the file created in the previous step, the formatting is working fine. I can add something the my trigger cell and the row borders are added

Clean up the new airport series and make it a dataframe with some other cols:

```
ap = ap.dropna()
ap.name = 'Existing Data'
ap = ap.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Information'})
ap.insert(len(ap.columns), 'Current Information?', np.nan)
ap.insert(len(ap.columns), 'Corrected Information', np.nan)
```

Define a writer and write the dataframe to the new file:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_ap_file, engine='openpyxl')
book = load_workbook(output_ap_file)
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

ap.to_excel(writer, index=False, startrow=start_row)

writer.save()
```

As stated before, the new file successfully retained existing cells from the template file, populated data in the correct range, even retained the rule for conditional formatting, but the actual format within the rule was reset.

At a bit of a loss, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it work if you use openpyxl directly? 2.2 should contain pretty complete support for conditional formatting.

Comment: @Charlie I just noticed I was somehow on an older (1.8.5) version of openpyxl while looking at the docs and updated to 2.0.2 (conda update) and it seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for the response and thanks for the work you do!